# compatibility problem with unicode file name in zip files

Tags: c#, java, unicode, zip

I am trying to compress a file that has unicode characters in it.

when im using winzip, nor winrar and window "compressed folder" view it normally.
when im using winrar, both winzip and winrar can view it, but not windows "compressed folder".

i tried many c# classes and change many encodings with no success.
i also tried apache common compressor with java and had no luck also.

it seems like windows "compressed folder" just cant view unicode characters in file names, but im asking you, do you know a way to encode a unicoded file in a zip so it will open in windows compressed folder properly?

thank you in advanced for any help.

Comment: There are different ways to encode filenames in zip files, no single one is standardized. For zip files to be used by java, the file names have to be encoded in UTF-8 (likes the `jar` tool does). I have no idea what encoding the *compressed folder view* wants. Best bet still is not to use non-ASCII-characters in file names, sadly.

Answer (score 2):

You can force 7-Zip to use unicode:

Right click, 7-Zip > Add to archive... > Write "cu" in the Parameters field.

Comment: That works great, where did you find that param? I was searching and didn't find any documentation on 7-zip.

Answer (score 1):

This scenario will likely not work. The ZIP functionality built into Windows has a number of well-known Unicode problems. These are described [here](http://www.siao2.com/2012/01/04/10252916.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use 7-Zip to create the ZIP archive. It's free Open Source from http://7-zip.org

Comment: 7-zip has the same problem. Actually it's worse because there is no warning, it just scrambles file names when added to an archive.

Answer (score -1):

[This hotfix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2704299) apparently solves the problem in Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2. Windows 8/10 I think is immune.